# WooCommerce - Will 2 products show as unique with the same cart item meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

If I have a product (eg. pen) on the Woocommerce shop that allows a custom field (Name Label), and I want to order 2 of these with different names (in the same order), will WC treat them as separate product because they have different cart item meta or will i need to add this in?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce will treat them as separate products because they have unique product (post) ids. Woocommerce products are technically posts and are stored in wp_posts table, which has an auto incrementing ID field. The custom fields are in wp_postmeta and are joined to each product on post_id.

Comment: Yes this I am aware of. I mean the same product (eg. Black Pen ID: 123) but a custom field (eg. Name Engraving). I want to order 2 pens at once but with diferent names (s post_id is the same), will it show as unique products